# Choosing between POST and GET

Tags: http, post, get

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [GET vs. POST (form processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668701/get-vs-post-form-processing)
>   [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

I'm interested in POST and GET. Why do I exactly need them and what is the difference between them? I know they both retrieve some data from some url, but that's probably all I know.

Comment: you mean in the mobile browser?

Comment: Start here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3 - they are one of the basic tools for accessing the web; in a very simplified shortcut: one is supposed to read webpages, the other is supposed to send data to webpages.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: they are HTTP methods and POST - posts and GET - gets data ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668701/get-vs-post-form-processing for a basic overview.

Answer (score 1):

GET is purely for retrieval. One of the most important aspects of GET is that GET is never allowed to change the state of the server (meaning: modifications).

POST does allow that.

This distinction is incredibly important. So if you're fetching info based on a couple of parameters/filters/etc. GET will do fine, but as soon as you're modifying anything on the server you MUST use POST.